# Error with Grails Executor plugin: getting <T> not found exception while compiling the project

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have downloaded grails executor plugin from https://github.com/basejump/grails-executor and placed it in the plugin folder of our application. When we trying to compile it using eclipse, we get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable<'T'> task) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                                                           ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable<'T'> task) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                   ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submitWithoutSession(java.util.concurrent.Callable<'T'> task) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                                                                         ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submitWithoutSession(java.util.concurrent.Callable<'T'> task) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                   ^
C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submitWithoutPersistence(java.util.concurrent.Callable<'T'> task) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                                                                             ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submitWithoutPersistence(java.util.concurrent.Callable<'T'> task) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                   ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submit(java.lang.Runnable task, java.lang.Object result) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                   ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submitWithoutSession(java.lang.Runnable task, java.lang.Object result) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                   ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:29: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submitWithoutPersistence(java.lang.Runnable task, java.lang.Object result) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                   ^

D:\WORKSPACE\Project_10303\src\java\AES1Delegate.java:20: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        ^

D:\WORKSPACE\Project_10303\src\java\AES1Delegate.java:20: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
                                    ^

D:\WORKSPACE\Project_10303\src\java\AES1Delegate.java:31: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        ^

D:\WORKSPACE\Project_10303\src\java\AES1Delegate.java:31: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
                                    ^

D:\WORKSPACE\Project_10303\src\java\FileConverter.java:98: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
                return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
                                   ^

D:\WORKSPACE\Project_10303\src\java\FileConverter.java:120: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
                byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);
                                         ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextCallableWrapper.java:12: grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextCallableWrapper is not abstract and does not override abstract method call() in java.util.concurrent.Callable
public class PersistenceContextCallableWrapper
       ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextCallableWrapper.java:19: call() in grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextCallableWrapper cannot implement call() in java.util.concurrent.Callable; attempting to use incompatible return type
found   : java.lang.Object
required: T
public java.lang.Object call() { return null;}
                        ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable<'T'> task) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                                                                                                          ^


C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submitWithoutSession(java.util.concurrent.Callable<'T'> task) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                                                                                                                        ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submitWithoutPersistence(java.util.concurrent.Callable<'T'> task) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                                                                                                                            ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submit(java.lang.Runnable task, java.lang.Object result) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                                                                                                                     ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submitWithoutSession(java.lang.Runnable task, java.lang.Object result) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
                                                                                                                                                   ^

C:\Users\laxmia\.grails\1.0.3\projects\Project_10303\generated-java-source\grails\plugin\executor\PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper.java:29: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class T
location: class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper
public java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'> submitWithoutPersistence(java.lang.Runnable task, java.lang.Object result) { return (java.util.concurrent.Future<'T'>)null;}
```

Where ever <'T'> and T is mentioned we are getting the compilation error. how to resolve this?

Please: Remove the '(quotes) in <'T'>

Comment: It seems like you are cutting off the important info. just post the **whole stack trace dump**

Comment: Just try **cleaning** and **refresh dependencies**. It is just complaining for nothing

Comment: I have already done that. But i'm not able to resolve it

Comment: Are you really using Grails 1.0.3? I doubt many plugins work with an ancient release like that

Comment: Yes we are using grails 1.0.3. BackgroundThread plugin is working. we need to include executor too.